Не меняется ревизия проекта при синхронизации инвентори в awx
У меня есть проблема с awx. У меня есть проект, который использует в качестве Source Control Type - Git, я включил опцию Update revision on job launch .
Также у меня есть инвентори в котором в качестве источника указан этот проект, и также включен флажок Update of launch.
Когда я запускаю sync для инвентори, то запускается обновление проекта, но ревизия проекта остается неизменной. Когда я запускаю обновление проекта в ручную, то ревизия обновляется
Как сделать так, чтобы ревизия проекта обновлялась автоматически при запуске синхронизации source inventory

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.
